# Backup on shutdown

Tags: backup, rsync, init.d

I am developing a system that runs an rsync every 15 min using cron. It rsync's the users directory to a local backup on another device.

I'd like to also run the rsync on shutdown or reboot.

How do I make sure the rsync doesn't run after the various unmounts on shutdown / reboot?

For details on the system see http://balsa.kkoncepts.net

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!